# jquery modifying the value of href

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I have a lot of links with the class `.moo`, I need jquery to scan the element for them, then to add a bit of text to the end of the href.

For example:

This is what I have:

```
<a href="http://root.net" class="moo">root.net</a>
```

and this is what I would like to have, after the jQuery magic happens:

```
<a href="http://root.net?iframe=true&amp;width=600&amp;height=300e" class="moo">root.net</a>
```

The reason I need this is a jquery plugin that eats this: `?iframe=true&amp;width=600&amp;height=300`.

Can this be done? I'm a jquery noob and I've been fiddling with prepend, etc, but I still don't get it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){
$(".moo").each(function(){
$(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href")+"?iframe=true&amp;width=600&amp;height=300");
});
});
```

that should work I think

Comment: this will work better if you do not know what your base url will be.

Comment: heh, we answered this at the exact same time with the same answer

Comment: I saw that - that's what happens with the low hanging fruit :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(".moo").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?iframe=true&amp;width=600&amp;height=300");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this not work?

$('.moo').attr('href', 'http://root.net?iframe=true&width=600&height=300e');